# How to set up a guest's public SSH key inside the DMZ?

Tags: macos, ssh

Utilizing the console, how does one check to see if they are inside the DMZ? I believe I am, but need to ensure this before adding a guests public SSH key?

The second part of the question is how to properly add a guest user's ssh key?

If this question seems obtuse, please let me know so I can add additional details.

Comment: Hi Charles, welcome to AskDifferent.  Do you mean DMZ when you create a wifi network using Mavericks?

Comment: Oh. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)

Comment: Let me get this right you have an ssh server in a DMZ which guests connect to and you then want to add the guest public ssh key to the DMZ server is that correct?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with shh,  I'm trying to debug a C++ compiler and the developer wants to assist me. He asked me to add his public key to my local node.JS server. Most of this is about my knowledge level – so not really sure which keywords to Google or the proper way to attack this.